# Layers not getting displayed using Map.addLayer in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, classification

I am writing a code to classify glacier features using various masks. The problem however is that none of the processed images are getting displayed. They are getting processed and the 'print' function is working fine as well, but the `Map.addLayer` function is not.
Only the 'apparent' final classified image shows up, which doesn't show the classes either. I am pretty new to GEE so don't know what to do exactly.

I am adding a snipped and link to the code.
[CODE](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fayushiid2526%2FNDVI_sushi%3Asimple),
[code_snapshot](https://code.earthengine.google.com/c9f849aff75b4eade7f92c4a93b761b2)

```js
// Load optical imagery 
var opticalImage = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2")
  .filterBounds(roi)
  .filterDate('2022-01-01', '2022-12-31')
  .median();

Map.addLayer(opticalImage);
print('Raw', opticalImage)

// Apply the CFMask to the image
var cfmask = opticalImage.select('QA_PIXEL');

// Create a mask where 'cfmask' is not equal to 0 (0 indicates clear pixels)
var cloudshadowMask = cfmask.neq(0);

// Apply the mask to the image to mask out clouds and cloud shadows
var maskedImage = opticalImage.updateMask(cloudshadowMask.not());

// Load Digital Elevation Model (DEM)
var dem = ee.Image('USGS/SRTMGL1_003');

// Calculate NDWI (Normalized Difference Water Index)
var ndwi = maskedImage.normalizedDifference(['SR_B3', 'SR_B5']).rename('NDWI');
Map.addLayer(ndwi)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your cloud masking code is wrong. You can see the meaning of the different bits in your image collection [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LC08_C02_T1_L2#bands). Bit `6` is clean. If you don't want to mask out water, look at bit `7` too. I've created a little utility method to deal with the bit-fiddling, so I don't have to think about it every time:

```
function bitwiseExtract(value, fromBit, toBit) {
  if (toBit === undefined)
    toBit = fromBit
  var maskSize = ee.Number(1).add(toBit).subtract(fromBit)
  var mask = ee.Number(1).leftShift(maskSize).subtract(1)
  return value.rightShift(fromBit).bitwiseAnd(mask)
}
```

Using this, your mask would look something like this:

```
var clearPixels = bitwiseExtract(cfmask, 6)
var water = bitwiseExtract(cfmask, 7)
var maskedImage = opticalImage.updateMask(clearPixels.or(water))
```